# Posting hebrew + english text on facebook wall, words get mixed up

Tags: java, facebook

I am posting on my FB wall using my java code:

```
FacebookType publishMessageResponse = facebookClient.publish(
    connection,
    FacebookType.class,
    Parameter.with(
        "message",
        fbMessageData.getRecipeOwnerName() +
            " posted " +
            fbMessageData.getRecipeName()
    )
);
```

The message should be: `Yoav posted מתכון`, however, it gets posted like this: `מתכון Yoav posted`. `מתכון` is the recipe name. The recipe name can be in English or Hebrew (UTF-8).

Any ideas on how to keep the order?

Comment: As far as I know, this is how a web browser usually displays mixed LTR and RTL text. Have you changed Facebook's display language to Hebrew to see if it's displayed correctly in Hebrew?

Comment: No,since it needs to be shown the same from either english or hebrew fb view

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using one of the Unicode BiDi_Control characters? Putting it in front of or around your recipe name …

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text

Comment: putting \u200F before and after the name?

Comment: I have tried putting \u200F or \u200E on the start of the post but it does not work

Comment: I can’t tell you if Facebook lets these chars get through, or maybe filters them out. Maybe that should be checked first, looking into the actual DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You should json_encode and then json_decode before sending to fb, it does the trick:

```
$album_details = array(
  'message'=> 'Live photos from our app',                      
  'name'=> $title, // This can be any non-english characters that can be in unicode
  'access_token'=>$pageAccessToken
);

$jsonStr = json_encode($album_details);
$decoded_album_settings = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

$create_album = $this->facebook->api('/'.$this->facebookPageId.'/albums', 'post', $decoded_album_settings);
```

The idea was taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3806967/1200166